# how to set an action button when creating an alarm clock using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, alarmmanager

I am trying my first project in python and wanted to create an alarm clock the ask the user to input the hour, minute and am or pm to set an alarm. I am having issues on how to set an action button so that when the user click on "set alarm", the alarm will be set.

```
import datetime

import winsound

import tkinter as tk

filename = "old-fashioned-door-bell.wav"

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Alarm Clock")

window.geometry("400x400")

window.configure(background="Brown")


def alarm_Clock():

    alarmHour = int(Entry1.get())

    alarmMinute = int(Entry2.get())

    amPm = str(Entry3.get())

    if (amPm == "pm"):

        alarmHour += 12

    while (1 == 1):

        if (alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and

            alarmMinute == datetime.datetime.now().minute):

            winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_LOOP)

            break

def update_btn():

    alarmHour, alarmMinute, amPM = Entry1.get(), Entry2.get(), Entry3.get()

    if alarmHour.isdigit() and alarmMinute.isdigit() and amPM.isdigit():

       return alarm_Clock()

Prompts1 = tk.Label(text="Kels Alarm Clock", font=("Times New Roman", 40), bg="brown", fg="white")

Prompts1.grid(column=0, row=0)

Prompts2 = tk.Label(text="Please enter the time Alarm should ring!", font=("Times New Roman", 15), 

bg="brown", fg="white")

Prompts2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="W")

Label1 = tk.Label(text="Enter Hour", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")

Label1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")

Label2 = tk.Label(text="Enter Minute", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")

Label2.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="W")

Label3 = tk.Label(text="Am or Pm", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")

Label3.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky="W")

Entry1 = tk.Entry()

Entry1.grid(column=1, row=2)

Entry2 = tk.Entry()

Entry2.grid(column=1, row=3)

Entry3 = tk.Entry()

Entry3.grid(column=1, row=4)

Button1 = tk.Button(text="Set Alarm", command="update_btn")

Button1.grid(column=1, row=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
import datetime
import winsound
import tkinter as tk

filename = "old-fashioned-door-bell.wav"

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Alarm Clock")
window.geometry("400x400")
window.configure(background="Brown")
def alarm_Clock():
    alarmHour = int(Entry1.get())
    alarmMinute = int(Entry2.get())
    amPm = str(Entry3.get())

    if (amPm == "pm"):
        alarmHour += 12

    while (1 == 1):
        if (alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and
            alarmMinute == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
            winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_LOOP)
            break

def update_btn():
    alarmHour, alarmMinute, amPM = Entry1.get(), Entry2.get(), Entry3.get()
    if alarmHour.isdigit() and alarmMinute.isdigit() and amPM.isdigit():
        return alarm_Clock()

Prompts1 = tk.Label(text="Kels Alarm Clock", font=("Times New Roman", 40), bg="brown", 
fg="white")
Prompts1.grid(column=0, row=0)
Prompts2 = tk.Label(text="Please enter the time Alarm should ring!", font=("Times New 
Roman", 15), bg="brown", fg="white")
Prompts2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="W")

Label1 = tk.Label(text="Enter Hour", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")
Label1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="W")
Label2 = tk.Label(text="Enter Minute", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")
Label2.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="W")
Label3 = tk.Label(text="Am or Pm", bg="brown", fg="white", font="Garamond")
Label3.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky="W")

Entry1 = tk.Entry()
Entry1.grid(column=1, row=2)
Entry2 = tk.Entry()
Entry2.grid(column=1, row=3)
Entry3 = tk.Entry()
Entry3.grid(column=1, row=4)

Button1 = tk.Button(text="Set Alarm", command="update_btn")
Button1.grid(column=1, row=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, there are a few errors in your code. Enter1, Enter2... is local to the function "update_btn()". To use it in other function pass it or use "global" keyword in the function "alarm_clk". If possible Post the entire code in the code section instead of chunks.